# Parametric equation for filled sphere

Tags: geometry, parametric, spheres

I have the following problem:

> A part, $\Omega$ of a filled sphere is given by:
>
> $$\Omega=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 | \: x^2+y^2+z^2 ≤1, x≥0, -x ≤y ≤x, z ≥0 \}$$
>
> Determine a parametric equation for $\Omega$.

Okay, so my first instinct was to look at the general equation for a filled sphere and then change the intervals so that it matched the requirements.

$$(x,y,z)=\bigg(\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi), \: \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),\: \cos(\theta)  \bigg),\theta\in[0,\pi], \:\phi\in[0,2\pi]$$

But when I change the intervals, for example instead of $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ I do $\theta\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ it no longer has the sphere shape.

Can someone help me with this problem?

**EDIT**

This is my plot in maple. And as you can see, it doesn't have a spherical shape.

[image]

But I think I figured it out. It's just the scaling that's messed up. If I used the scaling=constrained command I end up with this:

[image]

Which looks much better!

Comment: If it's a *filled* sphere you need $3$ parameters, not $2$, which would be spherical coordinates from your example.

Comment: Right, I can just add a parameter $r$ in the interval $[0,1]$ and there I have a filled sphere. But that doesn't really help me get further with this problem.

Comment: In this case you already have all the information you need, you just need to find appropriate restrictions for the angles. Did you try converting the boundaries into spherical coordinates?

Comment: If that's the case, I get the parametric equation to be: $s(r,\theta, \phi)=(r(\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi), \: r\sin(\theta) \sin(\phi), \: r\cos(\theta)) , r\in[0,1], \theta \in[0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \phi\in[0,\frac{3\pi}{2}]$

Comment: This is not correct. The correct angles are $\phi \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}\right]$

Comment: Oh shoot. I guess the final equation looks like this then: $s(r,\theta, \phi)=(r(\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi), \: r\sin(\theta) \sin(\phi), \: r\cos(\theta)) , r\in[0,1], \theta \in[0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \phi\in[\frac{-\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}]$

Answer (score 1):

So this is what I get when I plot what you prescribed.
[image]

'''
SphericalPlot3D[{1}, {[Theta], 0, Pi/2}, {[Phi], 0, 3 Pi/2}]
'''

And I am plotting in Mathematica. It is part of a sphere, where is the problem?

Comment: Hang on, I will edit my question and show my plot.